# WPF VB.NET ComboBox DataBinding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I'm new to LINQ to SQL and WPF and i'm using several online guides and YouTube Videos to pick this up (along with this application).

The problem:

On loading the window (and on other key data changes that refresh the Windows DataContext), I need to update what selected item the ComboBox is showing to the item with a matching ID from the Window DataContext binding (c_Instance.FK_RiskIndicator_ID)

I populate the ComboBox from a view which returns the display field and the ID (All ID's are GUIDs).

When the selection is changed, i call a Stored Procedure to update the DB with the ID of the selected item.

```
Private db As New AppDatabase_DBDataContext
Private CRCTypeView As BindingListCollectionView
Private InstanceDetailTypeView As BindingListCollectionView
Property guInstance_ID As Guid

Private Sub Refresh_PCA_Instance()
    Dim c_Instance As IEnumerable(Of t_Instance)
    c_Instance = (From Inst In db.t_Instances Where Inst.ID = guInstance_ID Select Inst)

    If c_Instance.Count = 1 Then
        Me.DataContext = c_Instance
        Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
    ElseIf c_Instance.Count > 1 Then
        Me.DataContext = c_Instance.First
        Me.InstanceDetailTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoadCRCType()
    Dim CRCTypeList As IEnumerable(Of vw_RiskIndicator)
    CRCTypeList = (From RiskIndicator In db.vw_RiskIndicators
                   Order By RiskIndicator.IndexNum
                   Select RiskIndicator)

    PCA_CRC_ComboBox.DataContext = CRCTypeList
    Me.CRCTypeView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PCA_CRC_ComboBox.DataContext), BindingListCollectionView)
End Sub

Private Sub PCA_CRC_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles PCA_CRC_ComboBox.SelectionChanged
    If PCA_CRC_ComboBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        db.sp_Instance_RiskIndicator_UPSERT(guInstance_ID, PCA_CRC_ComboBox.SelectedValue)
        Refresh_PCA_Instance() 'Refreshes the Window DataContext
    End If
End Sub
```

XAML for the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PCA_CRC_ComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    SelectedValuePath="ID"
    DisplayMemberPath="RiskIndicator"
    PreviewKeyDown="RiskIndicator_ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

I had assumed i could do this with binding the SelectedItem, but i can't figure it out. I had assumed it would be something like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PCA_CRC_ComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FK_RiskIndicator_ID}" <!--THIS LINE HERE-->
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    SelectedValuePath="ID"
    DisplayMemberPath="RiskIndicator"
    PreviewKeyDown="RiskIndicator_ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Grouped the code together. I assume this is what was meant. Personally i think this layout if less explanatory.

Comment: No offense, but this question is horribly written. I've been looking at it for a while tonight and I think I know how to help you, but it's late, and if nobody else has written a response by tomorrow, I will try and post an answer.

Comment: would you please edit this post and copy and paste all of your code (or as much as possible) XAML and code-behind?

Comment: I assume you mean to group it all together since i'm not going to drop 10k lines of irrelevant code into a forum post..

Comment: Yeah. I meant the relevant code, like all the event handlers and such.